# Foreach to ruby

Tags: ruby, translation

How would one translate a for each loop into ruby? I have a program that I need to translate from php to ruby. I have no clue how to do for each loops in ruby. If anybody could provide an example that would be awesome!

Comment: Give your `php` code atleast.

Comment: have you tried Googling **Ruby loop** ??

Comment: Basic googling would be sufficient to solve the problem.

Comment: hey Zachariah did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes thank you. We have found an answer to my problem anyways. Yet, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We have something similar to PHP:

```
[2] pry(main)> arr = [1,2,3]                                                             │
=> [1, 2, 3]                                                                              │
[3] pry(main)> for i in arr                                                               │
[3] pry(main)*   puts i                                                                   │
[3] pry(main)* end                                                                        │
1                                                                                         │
2                                                                                         │
3                                                                                         │
```